# Can i use org.apache.http.client.HttpClient in google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http

I read somwhere that goole just allowed only fetch. Does that mean it's impossible to integrate org.apache.http.client.HttpClient in google appe engine ?

If not, are there an alternative for using existing librairies using org.apache.http.client.HttpClient on google app engine ?

Comment: Did you look into using the [Google HTTP Client Library for Java](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/)? It supports Java 5+, Android 1.5+ and [also AppEngine](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/GoogleAppEngine).

Comment: The real question is : does apache's HttpClient use the file system ?
probably not, which means it probably works. It's just a layer over java.net.URL that makes it easier to use if I remember ?

Comment: This is a page for Google HTTP Client Library for Java on App engine https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/GoogleAppEngine. This is on a the page :"Do not try ApacheHttpTransport because it will definitely fail on Google App Engine."

Comment: @mcbjam, so the answer to your Q is, unfortunately, "no" -- could you please post a self-answer and accept it so it stops showing up as an "unanswered" question?  Pretty please...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is not. You need to use google fetch library.

From [Google App Engine wiki page on Google Code](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20121029184106/https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/GoogleAppEngine) as archived by [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/):

> The only supported HTTP transport is [UrlFetchTransport](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/extensions/appengine/http/UrlFetchTransport) based on URL Fetch Java API in the Google App Engine SDK
>
> Do not try [ApacheHttpTransport](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/http/apache/ApacheHttpTransport) because it will definitely fail on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2019

Yes, you can, indeed. I just tried, it works without fail with the Java 8 environment.

Steps:

1. Enable **billing**, otherwise the `native` `HttpURLConnection` won't work (which is also the basis of the Apache HttpClient). Without billing you can only use the legacy `urlfetch` as described in previous post from 2016.
2. Optional in Java 8 environment, since `native` is the default

`appengine-web.xml`:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <url-stream-handler>native</url-stream-handler>
</appengine-web-app>
```

3. Write your code, e.g.:

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://myservice.com");
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(input), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    return objectMapper.readValue(response.getEntity().getContent(), new TypeReference<MyReturnType>() { });
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```